# How to display coordinates of moving object in iOS?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

I am trying to display location of object that is moving by gesture. Everythink works fine untill I want to display its position. Below is code:

```
- (void)panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)panRecognizer
{
    CGPoint translation = [panRecognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint imageViewPosition = _iconCamera.center;
    imageViewPosition.x += translation.x;

     // This line generates error
    _labelCameraPosition.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.1f", _iconCamera.center.x];

    self.iconCamera.center = imageViewPosition;
    [panRecognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
```

When I want to display this value image is shaking but not moving. What should I do?

Comment: try getting the presentation layer of the object, and checking its frame: (CALayer*)self.iconCamera.layer.presentationLayer - this is used for the current position of views that are animating, not sure if it works in that case.

Comment: Why do you use _iconCamera a few times and self.iconCamera once?

Comment: its messy code for now. I just want make it working. I will care about consistency later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on that you are using auto layout.

in viewDidAppear, set your label and imageView like this.

```
self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
self.imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = YES;
```

since you are changing frame when using auto layout. set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to yes automatically translate its new frame to constraints.

Comment: I love this answer! Works perfectly! But I dont know why :-)

Comment: UIControl created by storyboard has its own constraints, and this property is NO by default,if you move the view around, changing its frame, the old constraints will try to break the change(the shaking). After setting to yes, the new frame automatically add new constraints to the view, which will make view moving smoothly.